# Detect which development or production push notification certificate in use programmatically

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement a push notification server.

So far, I have my Push server code in place and Push Feedback Service code in place.

One of the thing with push notification I have read in other Stackoverflow post was that we should not use a development certificate signed push token in a production certificate environment otherwise Apple's push server will disconnect our push notification server and prevent further push notification from getting through.

My question is, is it possible to use Objective C to detect which certificate the app was signed on launch?

On my server, I have a Token entity and one of the property was "environment" (either development or production).

At the moment, I am making the assumption that all submitted token is "development" token.

If I am able to find out which certificate (dev or prod) the app was signed with during app launch, then I could set the entity's environment property accordingly.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a predefined macro for that. In debug builds where the sandbox environment is used I define SANDBOX_ENVIRONMENT in the build settings.

That way I can add a parameter to the server call where the token is registered at the server.

Comment: Ahhhh, that clicks for me after I fired up Xcode :D I see. Essentially we can safely assume when we're ready to release the app, we obviously expect the push notification & feedback url to use the production one. Having that SANDBOX_ENVIRONMENT constant defined in preprocessor macro section identify to the code that our logic should use the appropriate url and parameter to our web service.

Comment: hey guys, I am new to Push Notifications. Can you tell me how to detect if Development or Production, I am facing this problem now and I have released the app to the app store!!!